# Задание имени для DisplayAttribute в классе родителе и наследнике

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть два класса:

```
    [ReportExport("Admin_Navigation_Rep2", "Rep2")]             
    class B :A
    {


    }


    [ReportExport("Admin_Navigation_Rep1", "Rep1")]     
    class A 
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "Admin_Report_InventoryCounted")]       
        public decimal InventoryCounted { get; set; }       

    }
```

Необходимо создать метод который при передаче параметра Name анализирует применение атрибута ReportExport к искомому классу - нужно отловить type 
внутри класса родителя и потомка. Дальнейшее извлечение MemberInfo из CustomAttributes - реализовано

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем обойдемся без рефлексии, а только через переорпределение свойств

```
    [ReportExport("Admin_Navigation_Rep2", "Rep2")]             
    class B :A
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "Admin_Report_InventoryCountedInherited")]       
        public override decimal InventoryCounted { get; set; }

    }


    [ReportExport("Admin_Navigation_Rep1", "Rep1")]     
    class A 
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "Admin_Report_InventoryCounted")]       
        public virtual decimal InventoryCounted { get; set; }       

    }
```